# Why was Documentation topic (CSS z-index) deleted?

Tags: discussion, documentation, deletion

I noticed a negative rep change on my page from the deletion a documentation page that had gotten an upvote previously.

I was somewhat dismayed, because I had spent much time authoring much of the post and making it a good-quality documentation. I created it in response to [this topic request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/topic-requests/1892), which had garnered *five* votes — not an unpopular request. <s>And now, the only documentation I can find on `z-index` under CSS is a (in my opinion) [rather wimpy single example under "Positioning"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/935/positioning/3917/overlapping-elements-z-index#t=201607222200186930495) that doesn't nearly answer it to the same degree.</s> (**Edit**: I updated this post)

The worst part about it, however, is that there was no notice on who deleted it, nor the reason for deleting. The page is simply now a [Page Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/5610).

I am not sure how the deletion process works in Documentation.

In summary,

- **Why was this post deleted?** (Where can I see the reason?)
- **How was this post deleted?**

[Here is the version of the page CSS `z-index` before it was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/1733/z-index#t=2016072219405349).

I also just noticed that there is the option to "Create draft rolling back to this version", so I'll do that if any answers/comments justify my opinion.

---

## Update

`z-index` has been moved to an example under [Positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/935/positioning/3917/overlapping-elements-z-index#t=201607222200186930495). Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I deleted it during clean-up of duplicate topics in the CSS language, because a separate topic is not at all necessary. The z-index property itself only applies to positioned elements and therefore it *belongs* in the topic about the rest of the positioning properties - not as a separate topic.

I assumed users received notifications for this like they receive notifications for rejected edits, but apparently not. But I didn't want to incorporate it in myself because a) simply copying it over would just create a duplicate example and b) editing it in myself would only steal credit for content others wrote. I do, however, think you should incorporate some of that information into the z-index example on the appropriate topic.

Comment: Thanks for the reasoning. I guess I'll just add to that topic now then.

Comment: Now remember that nothing is really deleted so long you get the link to it...

Comment: @Braiam I have the link for it ... for now. Who knows what [Community ♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) might do to clean up.